# Android: File Location

Tags: android, windows, file

I am writing to a path mnt/sdcard/foldername. I get no errors and the file is written, but when I browse the internal storage of my phone I can not find the folder. Where would the folder be located? I have a galaxy nexus?

Code is here:

```
             File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/statReporter/");
             directory.mkdirs();
             Log.d("Tag", directory.toString());
             //Path and name of XML file
             File file = new File(directory, appendTimeStamp("phoneNum") + ".csv");
             FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
             OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

             //Write to CSV File
             osw.write(message);
             osw.write(',');

             //Flush and close OutPutStreamWriter and close FileOutputStream
             osw.flush();
             osw.close();
             fOut.close();

             Log.d("File Logger:", "File write successfully!");
```

Cant find it in Windows Computer\Galaxy Nexus\Internal Storage but all other  folders appear.

I used an app called OI File Managaer and I can view the folder and file on phone but how do I view it through Windows OS?

Comment: how are you browsing your phone?

Comment: Just simple check it in External SD card folder name

Comment: If write to mnt/sdcard/foldername then you have to read from same path.. Not from internal storage..

Comment: Check my amended answer. I remembered that Eclipse allows you to browse your file structure via the DDMS perspective as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to find files on your device, I'd recommend one of the Google Play apps you can find (I personally like [ASTRO File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro)) or, from the PC you can use (for instance) [Android Commander](http://androidcommander.com/) (which, incidentally, will let you use the same file path structure you'll be using from within your developing environment).

I believe that Android devices will not actually show you all paths and available files when you browse it, for instance, with Windows Explorer.

If you're using Eclipse, in the DDMS perspective you can browse your device's file structure. On your right you have the "File Explorer" and as far as I remember, it's a pretty complete tool.

Comment: The problem is that on Windows I can see all folders, but it wont show the one I just created, seems as though it is hidden.

Comment: You mean adb shell? I dont really want to use that. I just want to connect my phone as a media device and grab the file.

Comment: I could try that, but I shouldn't have to install more software. I can see all the other folders with windows fine. It pulls mnt/sdcard for the other folders but the one I created.

Comment: ... don't know how I can help you then. It's either a problem with Windows not refreshing the folder structure or Android not allowing it to see it. There may be ways around that but they'll probably all involve installing plugins or editing the registry or somesuch. 
An alternative might involve disconnecting and reconnecting your device

Answer (score 0):

Don't use /mnt/sdcard for accessing external storage. You can use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to access path to external storage. This may vary from device to device.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.

Comment: You haven't posted code at first. That why I replied like above. Code looks good. Have you specified WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in android manifest?